# python installed by brew permission denied

Tags: homebrew, permission-denied

I have installed python2.7 by admin user on my Mac, which I can use as long as I'm logged in with the same user. Now with my normal user I'd like to access the newly installed version, but I get Permission denied!

How could I install packages and update them by my admin user (which has root permission) but keep everything similar between users?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use virtualenv+pip?

Comment: @PeterKlipfel or `conda`, if you want to isolate non-python libraries, too (including a Python interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [**umask**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) for each user.

Add this code to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
umask 0002
```

Then give group permission to users:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/
```

change owner to staff:

```
 sudo chgrp -R staff /usr/local
```